# How do you skip the Mike Tyson cut scene?

Tags: i-wanna-be-the-guy

In IWBTG (I Wanna Be The Guy), the cut scene just before fighting Mike Tyson is incredibly long and irritating to watch on each replay. Is there any way to skip the cut scene?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. The <kbd>S</kbd> key is used to skip cutscenes within IWBTG.

Comment: Hah, I just realized there's a way to view keybindings. I feel like at some point that wasn't a feature, I guess it's been a long time.

Comment: You can also skip the Dracula cut scene like this as well